# Saving XElement to a byte array

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have following piece of code, it writes some data but not all. What can cut my data ?

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlTextWriter xwr = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    service.getXElement.WriteTo(xwr);
    byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Are you properly disposing of `writeStream`?

Comment: @juharr I'm not sure. How can I do it properly ?

Comment: One of the easiest ways is to wrap writestream in a using block the same as you did for stream.

Comment: @tinstaafl Oh, I don't create `writeStream`. It is just parameter of `override` method : `public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)` in `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` class

Comment: @Vsevywniy In that case try adding a `writeStream.Flush()` after the `Write`. But really you must be passing it in from somewhere and that is where you need to make sure it is disposed.

Comment: @juharr I've tried, there is no changes